# "How to fix 'Custom pagination 404 error' in PHP

Tags: wordpress

I'm facing  problem in my custom post pagination. The custom pagination is work fine on single page with same code but it is not working on another page.

I have updated the permalink many times but nothing happen. I also update .htaccess file.

My source code listed here...

```
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                        <p class="main_dv"><?php
                            //$count=1;
                            $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
                                $data= new WP_Query(array(
                                'post_type'=>'software',// your post type name
                                'category_name' => 'general_software', // your category name
                                'posts_per_page' => 5, // post per page
                                'paged' => $paged,));
                                if($data->have_posts()) :
                                while($data->have_posts())  : $data->the_post();?>
                            <div class="testcustompost1">
                                <div class="pst_div">
                                <div class="thumb">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail();?> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="title_des">
                                <div class="title">
                                    <?php the_title();?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="description">
                                    <?php the_content();?>  
                                </div>
                                <div class="downlod_btn">
                                    <button class="btn"><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"> Download </a></button>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php //$count++;
                            endwhile;

                            echo '<div class="paginat_design">';
                            $total_pages = $data->max_num_pages;
                            if ($total_pages > 1){
                            $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
                            echo paginate_links(array(
                                        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                                        'format' => '/page/%#%',
                                        'current' => $current_page,
                                        'total' => $total_pages,
                                        'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
                                        'next_text'    => __('next »'),
                                    ));
                                }
                            echo '</div>'?>
                                <?php else :?>
                                <?php _e('404 Error&#58; Not Found', ''); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php wp_reset_postdata();?> 
                        </p>

                    </div>
```

404 Not found error

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
<?php
        /**
         * Looping through the content
         */
        $page = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;
        $data = new WP_Query (array(
                        'post_type'=>'software',
                        'category_name' => 'general_software', 
                        'posts_per_page' => 5,
                        'page' => $page
                    )); ?>
        <?php while ($data -> have_posts()) : $data -> the_post(); ?>
            <!-- Your html code here -->
        <?php endwhile; ?><?php wp_reset_query(); ?><?php wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

Here is the pagination part:

```
<?php
            echo paginate_links( array(
                'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                'total'        => $data->max_num_pages,
                'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'page' ) ),
                'format'       => '?page=%#%',
                'show_all'     => false,
                'type'         => 'plain',
                'end_size'     => 2,
                'mid_size'     => 1,
                'prev_next'    => true,
                'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Previous Page', 'text-domain' ) ),
                'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Next Page', 'text-domain' ) ),
                'add_args'     => false,
                'add_fragment' => '',
            ) );
?>
```

Let me know if it is this help you. If not, try to change the value from `paged` to `page`.

Comment: When you click on the Next page, which link do you get?

Comment: 404 Not found error

`Example :
URL : www.domain.com/pagename/page/2`

Comment: Can you try one more time, I've re-edited the code per you `URL`.

Comment: Can you try to put the Permalink on the `Post name`? Also, does debugger sent you some error?

Comment: Permalink is also `Post name`... I have solved my problem without changing any code in my previous code. But Now I am not able to understand that why it is happening...

When I change the my page slug `www.domainname.com/pagename` to `www.domainname.com/page-name` then it is working fine...but i don't want to change my page slug..

It is not working in a single page name... Like : `Software`  If we will change it `xyz-software` then working like a charm!